# AutoHotKey: Look for variable in associative array and return the value

Tags: arrays, object, autohotkey, associative-array

I'm working on a script to convert bible reference to bible verses. If I provide the reference 'John 1:1' it should parse the text from a particular website. In the case John 1:1, this website uses the url 'http://example.org/ref_43-1-1' where 43 being the 43rd book of bible (John). So I need to convert the variable 'John' to 43.
For this I've created an associative array.

```
bible_books := {Matthews:40, Mark:41, Luke:42, John:43}
```

What I need is:

1. Search with the variable 'John' to determine whether it exists as key in the array.
2. If it exists, return the value of that key

I think the commands `InStr()`, `if Var in/contains MatchList`, `Object.HasKey(Key)` are somewhat similar to what I need here. But I don't know how to implement in an array.

Note: All the other parts including getting the actually verses have already implemented. This is the only part I'm stuck at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for this,

```
if bible_books.HasKey(Key)
{
   MsgBox % value := bible_books[key]
}
```

Explanaion:

```
`Object.HasKey`
```

Returns true if Key is associated with a value (even "") within Object, otherwise false. [Link](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/objects/Object.htm#HasKey)

I declared 'key' as the input variable so that it will return the value from the associative array.